# Error in getting network figure in python networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm running this code to get a network figure. I'm using networkx package in python.

```
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 10
pos = nx.spring_layout(g, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(g.order()))
d = dict(g.degree)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
nx.draw(g, pos, node_color='green', 
        with_labels=True, 
        nodelist=d, 
        node_size=[d[k]*200 for k in d])
```

But getting the following error. This code runs fine in Kaggle or Colab but problem occurs when I try to run this segment in jupyter Notebook of my computer.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _random_state(func, *args, **kwargs)
    395         try:
--> 396             random_state_arg = args[random_state_index]
    397         except TypeError as e:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NetworkXError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-83602777a5ba> in <module>
      1 from pylab import rcParams
      2 rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 10
----> 3 pos = nx.spring_layout(g, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(g.order()))
      4 d = dict(g.degree)
      5 plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    229             if not kwsyntax:
    230                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
--> 231             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    232     fun.__name__ = func.__name__
    233     fun.__doc__ = func.__doc__

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _random_state(func, *args, **kwargs)
    398             raise nx.NetworkXError("random_state_index must be an integer") from e
    399         except IndexError as e:
--> 400             raise nx.NetworkXError("random_state_index is incorrect") from e
    401 
    402         # Create a numpy.random.RandomState instance

NetworkXError: random_state_index is incorrect
```

Any solution anyone?

Comment: this code gives different errors becaue you forgot `import networkx as nx` and you didn't define `g`. And you forget `import numpy as np` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: I actually imported all of the packages you mentioned. Also defined g. As I mentioned before, this code runs perfectly on Kaggle or colab.

Comment: Can you check which `networkx` version you have installed? Online and offline? I have networkx version 2.5.1 and it runs without issues.

Comment: you could add all needed libraries and elements so we could also run it and see if it makes problem with different Python versions or `networkx` versions.

Comment: @Sparky05 thanks, mate. I had the **network** version 2.5 installed. Upgrading it to 2.6.3 solved the issue.